# How to validate date input between two dates in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, validation, input

I am trying to validate user input of date of birth. I have used datetime to validate that it's a valid existing date, however I am trying to make it so you can only enter dates between 1/1/1900 and the current date. I am using .today(), however I am very confused by the importing of datetime and date, and can't seem to get it working.

I also want to zero pad the dates so everything entered is in the format dd/mm/yyyy, either by forcing them to enter it like that, or by converting it to that format afterwads

Any help would be grately appreciated :)

[image: current code, I am sure that the import is wrong but I'm very confused of the difference between import datetime, from datetime import datetime, etc][image: error log as it is recognising todays_date as a datetime object rather than an integer]

Comment: What do you expect here: `int("01/01/1900")`? Even Python can't do magic ;-) If you want to compare dates as string, you can do that as well but the attributes need to be in decreasing order, so year-month-day-... and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out!! It wouldn't let me compare a string and a datetime object, and I tried converting them all to strings but couldn't do it, so very stupidly thought integers would work. Turns out I need to compare them as datetime objects rather than strings, so all I had to do was use strptime on the minimum date string :)